# Python threading and GIL

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, gil

I was reading about the GIL and it never really specified if this includes the main thread or not (i assume so). Reason I ask is because I have a program with threads setup that modify a dictionary. The main thread adds/deletes based on player input while a thread loops the data updating and changing data.

However in some cases a thread may iterate over the dictionary keys where one could delete them. If there is a so called GIL and they are run sequentially, why am I getting dict changed errors? If only one is suppose to run at a time, then technically this should not happen.

Can anyone shed some light on such a thing? Thank you.

Comment: Generally, Python threading only makes sense for I/O-bound threads. If you want consistency accessing data structures in parallel, you need explicit locking. If you need CPU-bound parallelism, usually you have to use something entirely different.

Comment: cpu-bound tasks should be run using multiprocessing in lieu of threads. using message-queues as task queues with many workers pulling tasks (or having them pushed) is one such scenario for python parallelism.

Answer (score 11):

They are **running** at the same time, they just don't **execute** at the same time. The iterations might be interleaved. Quote Python:

> The mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that only one thread **executes** Python **bytecode** at a time.

So two `for` loops might run at the same time, there will just be no (for example) two `del dict[index]`'s at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

The GIL locks at a Python byte-code level, and applies to all threads, even the main thread.  If you have one thread modifying a dictionary, and another iterating keys, they will interfere with each other.

"Only one runs at a time" is true, but you have to understand the unit of granularity.  In the case of CPython's GIL, the granularity is a bytecode instruction, so execution can switch between threads at any bytecode.

Comment: from Python glossary page `GIL The mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that only one thread executes Python bytecode at a time. This simplifies the CPython implementation by making the object model (including critical built-in types such as dict) implicitly safe against concurrent access.` If I am not wrong, this means dict is thread safe?

Comment: It depends on the operations you perform on the dict.  This is not thread-safe:  `d[k] += 1`.  When in doubt, use your own synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

The gil prevents two threads from modifying the interpreter state simultaneously.  It doesn't provide any thread consistency constraints, or any kind of mutex at all on a granularity smaller than the whole process.   If you need to read and modify a dict in two threads, you should be using a mutex

Answer (score 1):

Python switches threads more often than you seem to think it does. You say "only one" is supposed to run at a time, and technically that's true, but it depends on your definition of "one." Python's atomic operations are very small. For example: adding a single item to a dictionary. Iteration over an entire dictionary can be interrupted.

You should use a lock object from the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) library to isolate your program's atomic operations.