# Python Multi-threading in a recordset

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, lambda

I have a database record set (approx. 1000 rows) and I am currently iterating through them, to integrate more data using extra db query for each record.

Doing that, raises the overall process time to maybe 100 seconds.

What I want to do is share the functionality to 2-4 processes.

I am using Python 2.7 to have AWS Lambda compatibility.

```
def handler(event, context):

    try:

        records = connection.get_users()

        mandrill_client = open_mandrill_connection()

        mandrill_messages = get_mandrill_messages()

        mandrill_template = 'POINTS weekly-report-to-user'

        start_time = time.time()

        messages = build_messages(mandrill_messages, records)

        print("OVERALL: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

        send_mandrill_message(mandrill_client, mandrill_template, messages)

        connection.close_database_connection()

        return "Process Completed"

    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
```

Following is the function which I want to put into threads:

```
def build_messages(messages, records):

for record in records:

    record = dict(record)

    stream = get_user_stream(record)

    data = compile_loyalty_stream(stream)

    messages['to'].append({
        'email': record['email'],
        'type': 'to'
    })

    messages['merge_vars'].append({
        'rcpt': record['email'],
        'vars': [
            {
                'name': 'total_points',
                'content': record['total_points']
            },
            {
                'name': 'total_week',
                'content': record['week_points']
            },
            {
                'name': 'stream_greek',
                'content': data['el']
            },
            {
                'name': 'stream_english',
                'content': data['en']
            }
        ]
    })

return messages
```

What I have tried is importing the multiprocessing library:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
```

Created a pool inside the **try** block and mapped the function inside this pool:

```
pool = ThreadPool(4)

messages = pool.map(build_messages_in, itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(mandrill_messages), records))

def build_messages_in(a_b):
    build_msg(*a_b)


def build_msg(a, b):
    return build_messages(a, b)

def get_user_stream(record):

    response = []

    i = 0

    for mod, mod_id, act, p, act_created in izip(record['models'], record['model_ids'], record['actions'],
                                                 record['points'], record['action_creation']):

        information = get_reference(mod, mod_id)

        if information:

            response.append({
                'action': act,
                'points': p,
                'created': act_created,
                'info': information
            })

            if (act == 'invite_friend') \
                    or (act == 'donate') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_500_general') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_1000_general') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_500_cancel') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_1000_cancel'):

                response[i]['info']['date_ref'] = act_created
                response[i]['info']['slug'] = 'attiki'

            if (act == 'bonus_500_general') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_1000_general') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_500_cancel') \
                    or (act == 'bonus_1000_cancel'):

                response[i]['info']['title'] = ''

            i += 1

    return response
```

Finally I removed the **for** loop from the build_message function.

What I get as a results is a 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: @GhostCat I submitted the question and forgot to write down what I have tried. Here is some code which works, below is some code that supposed to work but it doesn't. Basically I am trying to multi-process the build_messages function.

Comment: Great. Now let the experts come in to help you ;-)

Comment: You haven't said where you're getting that error. From what I can gather, this is using the `mailchimp` API and I'm assuming that the longest wait is for an API response?

Comment: @roganjosh ignore the mailchimp API call, it takes 1 second to finish for a thousand mails. The error is coming from build_messages.

Comment: @mallix but from where in `build_messages`? If you removed the `for` loop then I can't see anywhere where you are iterating?

Comment: @roganjosh do I need to iterate when I m trying to implement this via threads?

Comment: More what I'm getting at: rather than trying to do this through multithreading in `build_messages`, can you isolate the part of the code that takes so long? Because the only thing I can see is `get_user_stream` and `compile_user_stream`, for which we cannot see the contents. Before battling with multithreading, it's worth seeing if it will give you any speedup. Often it won't.

Comment: For example, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728974/is-my-python-multithreading-code-affected-by-the-global-interpreter-lock/39729183?noredirect=1#comment66756464_39729183

Comment: @roganjosh yes get_user_stream is the reason. Mainly because get_reference is another database call.

Comment: We might be going down a rabbit hole on this _specific_ example :) Is `get_information` querying the db via `requests` library? If so, I could give you some generic code so you can try split those calls across multiple processes (`multiprocessing` rather than `multithreading`) i.e. each process runs in parallel and only has to do 250 calls... close to 1/4 of the time, plus a bit of overhead. It wouldn't be a complete answer but might put you on the right path.

Comment: @roganjosh I am using psycopg2 for Postgres for querying the database. This sounds interesting though.

Comment: @mallix I'll prepare something more generic then and give some pointers; I don't know if someone could give you some thing more specific eventually. It will take me a little while.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems pretty in-depth and so you cannot be sure that `multithreading` will lead to any performance gains when applied on a high level. Therefore, it's worth digging down to the point that gives you the largest latency and considering how to approach the specific bottleneck. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/python-what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modul) for greater discussion on threading limitations.

If, for example as we discussed in comments, you can pinpoint a single task that is taking a long time, then you could try to parallelize it using `multiprocessing` instead - to leverage more of your CPU power. Here is a generic example that hopefully is simple enough to understand to mirror your Postgres queries without going into your own code base; I think that's an unfeasible amount of effort tbh.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import datetime as dt

MAILCHIMP_RESPONSE = [x for x in range(1000)]

def chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]


def db_query():
    ''' Delayed response from database '''
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return random.random()


def do_queries(query_list):
    ''' The function that takes all your query ids and executes them 
    sequentially for each id '''
    results = []
    for item in query_list:
        query = db_query()
        # Your super-quick processing of the Postgres response
        processing_result = query * 2
        results.append([item, processing_result])
    return results


def single_processing():
    ''' As you do now - equivalent to get_reference '''
    result_of_process = do_queries(MAILCHIMP_RESPONSE)
    return result_of_process


def multi_process(chunked_data, queue):
    ''' Same as single_processing, except we put our results in queue rather
    than returning them '''
    result_of_process = do_queries(chunked_data)
    queue.put(result_of_process)


def multiprocess_handler():
    ''' Divide and conquor on our db requests. We split the mailchimp response
    into a series of chunks and fire our queries simultaneously. Thus, each
    concurrent process has a smaller number of queries to make '''

    num_processes = 4 # depending on cores/resources
    size_chunk = len(MAILCHIMP_RESPONSE) / num_processes
    chunked_queries = chunks(MAILCHIMP_RESPONSE, size_chunk)

    queue = mp.Queue() # This is going to combine all the results

    processes = [mp.Process(target=multi_process, 
                args=(chunked_queries[x], queue)) for x in range(num_processes)]

    for p in processes: p.start()

    divide_and_conquor_result = []
    for p in processes:
        divide_and_conquor_result.extend(queue.get())

    return divide_and_conquor_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_single = dt.datetime.now()

    single_process = single_processing()

    print "Single process took {}".format(dt.datetime.now() - start_single)
    print "Number of records processed = {}".format(len(single_process))

    start_multi = dt.datetime.now()

    multi = multiprocess_handler()

    print "Multi process took {}".format(dt.datetime.now() - start_multi)
    print "Number of records processed = {}".format(len(multi))
```